# _ldap.get_option(_ldap.OPT_API_INFO) is slow after upgrading to MacOS Mojave

Tags: python, macos, ldap

Recently I have noticed my Django project starts up much slower comparing to a month ago, typically 5~6 seconds slower, I don't remember updating any packages and also validated on Ubuntu server that it doesn't suffer the same problem, so my only guess is that due to my MacOS upgrade.

So I ran python profiler:

```
python -m cProfile -o /tmp/result manage.py
```

Then inspected the result using `snakeviz`:

```
snakeviz /tmp/result
```

This indicated the slowness is in the ldap package by hovering  `__init__.py:5`:

[image]

Then I went into the `__init__.py` and discovered that the following line took the most of the time:

`LIBLDAP_API_INFO = _ldap.get_option(_ldap.OPT_API_INFO)`

Further digging into `get_option` it goes into source code of `_ldap.cpython-36m-darwin.so`

```
def get_option(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    pass
```

Just wondering if anyone is having similar issues and how to fix it?

Comment: Running into the same issue with a dummy `slapd` instance (v2.4.45) used for running tests on my Gentoo box. Recompiling `openldap` and reinstalling `python-ldap` via `pip install python-ldap --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir` helps, but not for too long. Will open a bounty on this question if won't find the solution within a day.

Comment: I still haven't got to solve the problem yet, would be great to hear an update from you @hoefling

Comment: In my case, it was an extremely slow DNS server used by my company's VPN connection (5 seconds delay on each DNS lookup query). Spinning up a local `dnsmasq` instance with restricting usage of the slow DNS server to a restricted list of domains solved the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting dive into the profiler. I think the solution is presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328378/python-ldap-macos-valueerror-option-error

Comment: @mvreijn it's a bit different, mine works fine, just slow, no errors.